# Why is ORDER BY incorrectly sorting fields from a custom metadata type?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-metadata

I have a SOQL query on one of my org's custom metadata types that looks like:

```
List<Metadata_Type__mdt> = [ SELECT String1__c, String2__c
                               FROM Metadata_Type__mdt
                              WHERE Number__c > 0
                           ORDER BY Number__c asc ];
```

In this case `String1__c` and `String2__c` are both text fields and `Number__c` is a number field we use to sort the custom metadata records. When I look at the results of this query, though, they are ordered in such a fashion that the `Number__c` value for the records (in returned order) would look like `5, 7, 3, 4, 1, 6, 2`. I also have something similar happen with another custom metadata type query that sorts using a text field.

Is there something missing or incorrect with this query that could be causing a malformed `ORDER BY` result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it is a bug in the way ORDER BY is applied, but if you want it to work you have to include the ORDER BY field in the SELECT output, like:

```
SELECT String1__c, String2__c, Number__c
    FROM Metadata_Type__mdt
    WHERE Number__c > 0
    ORDER BY Number__c ASC
```

**EDIT**: Salesforce created a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BreQAE&title=custom-metadata-type-not-being-sorted-as-expected) for this and the fix is in flight (though seems to have stalled as the last update was 11 months ago).